# Overloading << operator for Array of Arrays

Tags: c++

I have defined the following function in the header of my class Array1 which prints the length of the array and it works.

```
 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out,Array1<T> x)
 {
     out<<x.length();
 }
```

But how can I use the << operator to print the total length of objects like

```
 Array1<Array1<double>> myarray;
```

Comment: missing `>` in `(std::ostream &out,Array1< Array1<T> x)`

Comment: Thank you I have edited it .

Comment: It still won't compile - `Array<T>*` doesn't match the type of `x` (unless there is some sneaky implicit conversion defined). Could you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I have made the problem more clear,thank you for the info!

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense to me. The length of `myarray` shouldn't be determined by the type it's holding. Well, but besides that logic issue, why don't you just loop through `myarray` and go like `sum += myarray[i].length();`

Comment: I tried making pointer Array1<double> *p = x ,but the compiler says it is illegal conversion

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

// I don't know what your Array1 looks like but for this demo
// deriving from std::vector seems reasonable
template<class T> struct Array1 : std::vector<T>
{

};

// general case of computing a length of an array
template<class T> std::size_t totalArrayLength(Array1<T> const& a)
{
    return a.size();
}

// specific case of an array of arrays
template<class T> std::size_t totalArrayLength(Array1<Array1<T>> const& a)
{
    auto total = std::size_t(0);
    for (auto const& i : a) {
        total += totalArrayLength(i);
    }
    return total;
}


// defer to the totalArrayLength function overloads for length
// computation
template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Array1<T>& a)
{
    return os << totalArrayLength(a);
}

int main()
{
    Array1<Array1<int>> a;
    a.push_back({});
    a.push_back({});
    a[0].push_back(1);
    a[0].push_back(2);
    a[0].push_back(3);
    a[1].push_back(4);
    a[1].push_back(5);
    a[1].push_back(6);

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    // works with any number of dimensions
    Array1<Array1<Array1<int>>> aaa;
    aaa.push_back(a);
    aaa.push_back(a);
    std::cout << aaa << std::endl;
}
```